# Woocommerce: check if current product is in a child category of 'XXX'

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm working on WP single.php (woocommerce installed).
I need to check if current page is a product page: if yes, also check if this product is in a child category of XXX.

I found this piece of code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'post_is_in_descendant_category' ) ) {
    function post_is_in_descendant_category( $cats, $_post = null ) {
        foreach ( (array) $cats as $cat ) {
            // get_term_children() accepts integer ID only
            $descendants = get_term_children( (int) $cat, 'category' );
            if ( $descendants && in_category( $descendants, $_post ) )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine on my regular pages, but not on my product pages.

Now I currently use this code:

```
if ( is_product() && has_term( 'XXX', 'product_cat' ) ) {
```

The problem is this doesn't check for child categories. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are using only checks the category taxonomy. use this one on product pages.  I've replace 'category' with 'product_cat' and replaced `in_category` with `has_term` since that only works on categories

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('product_is_in_descendant_category')) {
    function product_is_in_descendant_category($cats, $_post = null)
    {
        foreach ((array)$cats as $cat) {
// get_term_children() accepts integer ID only
            $descendants = get_term_children((int)$cat, 'product_cat');
            if ($descendants && has_term($descendants, 'product_cat', $_post)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

or add a third parameter to the original function that reads $tax = 'category' and replace 'category' with $tax on line 5. then when you call the function on product pages pass 'product_cat' as the third parameter.  FYI doing it this way would also require you to replace `in_category` with `has_term`